Reference on the quantization of Polyakov action at higher genus
Despite my searches, I was unable to find a good reference on this topic. I was looking for a reference about quantization of the Polyakov action for an arbitrary Riemann surface. I am thankful to everyone who introduce me some relevant papers, books,...

This is dicussed in Polchinski’s textbook. Are you looking for something more than what is there?

Yeah, I am searching for mode expansions of $X$ in different patches (which is trivial), holomorphic transition functions and how genus $g$ shows itself in the equations. Polchinski's textbook does not discuss about it.
